# Use of "decreases"

Tags: sentence-construction

Is use of "decreases" in the following sentence correct grammatically and conceptually? If it is not, kindly suggest ways to make it clearer.

> This causes better performance in VTB than the CTB. Therefore, the VTB
>   is cleaner than the CTB because the amount of fossil fuels consumption
>   and air pollution **decreases** in order to produce the electrical
>   energy.

Comment: You would want "from VTB than CTB" and "consumption of fossil fuels" as well as "decrease" (singular).

Comment: Is this a translation from another language? There are several problems here.

Comment: Sometimes a question like this suggests a "smell". The smell suggests a bigger problem.  It might be better to say, "It is cleaner to use/do/process VTB because it requires less fossil fuels and generates less air polution to produce the same electrical energy as CTB."  Emphasize VTB and its benefits first.

Comment: Does it actually reduce air pollution, or just generate less air pollution than alternatives (other than doing nothing)?

Answer (score 0):

> Is use of "decreases" in the following sentence correct grammatically and conceptually?

"decreases" is singular. It should be "decrease" for plural.
Overall, the sentence is not clear.

> If it is not, kindly suggest ways to make it clearer.

Here is a rewrite:

> This leads to better performance in the VTB than the CTB. Therefore, the VTB is a cleaner source of energy than the CTB; the consumption of fossil fuels is less, and in turn air pollution has also decreased.

or

> This leads to better performance in the VTB than the CTB. Therefore, the VTB is a cleaner source of energy than the CTB, due to the fact that the consumption of fossil fuels is now lower, which in turn decreases air pollution as well.

It is still unclear from the question what the VTB and CTB are though. A cleaner "consumer of energy",  or "source of energy", or if neither of those precisely, then  swap in this text: "Therefore, the VTB is an environmentally cleaner solution than the CTB"

Comment: A simpler edit, in addition to "decrease", would be to change consumption to consumed.

Answer (score 0):

The plural of the noun amount is amounts.  If you are using the singular noun (amount), it will take a singular verb.  On the other hand, the plural noun (amounts) will take a plural verb.

In the sentence presented, you are referring to the singular noun (amount), so the singular verb i,e, decreases is grammatical.